# Moving Expression engine site from Live Server to Localhost

Tags: localhost

Please advice me on how to move Expression engine site from Live Server  to Localhost

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty straight forward to move an EE site.

The instructions from EllisLabs are pretty comprehensive - [EE server migration instructions](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/operations/moving.html).

Comment: I followed EE server migration instructions.

Comment: Moved EE 2.5.5 site to localhost and RESULT :An Error Was Encountered Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferenes; No Preferences Found

Comment: That sounds very much like a problem hooking up your local site to the MySQL database - I'd check that you've got the database.php settings correct on the migrated file.